# asctec_mav_framework GPS based position control

Tags: ros, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would like to use asctec_mav_framework ros package with my pelican, however I would like to know if I can do GPS based position control using this package.

I see that I can set ~position_control to 'GPS', however the documentation says:

"Sending GPS waypoints over the HLP to the LLP is currently not implemented as it is not available on the interface between HLP and LLP."

What does that statement mean? Does it mean I can't send Lat/Long waypoint, but can set position in meters, relative to the home?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12966/asctec_mav_framework-gps-based-position-control/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that's true, you could always just convert those GPS coordinates to UTM, and it act like a waypoint set in meters. That conversion can be found in the `gps_common` package in the `conversions.h` header.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0